# yarn start : Could not find or load main class start

Tags: reactjs, homebrew, create-react-app, yarnpkg

When I am trying to run react project(using create-react-app) using yarn start, It gives me an error that Could not find or load main class start. I have installed yarn using Homebrew. How to run using yarn?

Comment: sounds like you're not in the right folder. can you confirm you're running `yarn start` from the directory that has `package.json` ?

Comment: I checked. I am in the right directory.

Comment: does it also fail with `npm start` ?

Comment: no, it is perfectly fine with "npm start"

Answer (score 2):

This could be cause you have Hadoop YARN in your environnement variables. Check your env path and edit it to reach the js yarn package cli.

Edit:

1. Check if your global env `PATH` contains Hadoop YARN CLI.
2. If so, remove it from there and create new env vars for Hadoop modules & components. [I have the following](https://pastebin.com/yUCSj1kU) `HADOOP_HOME`, `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`, `YARN_CLASSPATH`. You can leave `HADOOP_HOME` in your `PATH` (as well as some other modules CLI, like Py/Spark).
3. Then, be sure that the js yarn cli is in your global `PATH` (something like this I guess `~\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin`).

[Command lines](https://gist.github.com/belgacea/4112b5e02e9de7a1fca0f588b2cec50e) depends on your OS.

Comment: how do you do this can you please be precise?

Comment: @Arjjun I edited my answer. Is it clear now ?